# Проблемы с переключением на alert в selenium python

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Задача стоит такая, что нужно c помощью selenium python зайти в личный кабинет https://www.bgoperator.ru/personal.jsp.
При попытки захода, появляется alert, на который я НИКАКИМ образом не могу переключиться. Происходит это все примерно так:
driver.get('адрес выше') ->
Процесс выполнения, который никак не заканчивается -> 
TimeoutException 
Видел множество решений по переключению на alert, но все они подразумевают действия после выполнения driver.get(), когда как у меня она стоит на месте и ожидает. Пробовал и с Options() поэкспериментировать, но безуспешно. Если кто-то сталкивался с подобной проблемой, поделитесь опытом, буду благодарен.

Comment: Это не алерт, а basic авторизация. Ее можно передавать в адресе. Ниже уже ответилии как.

Comment: @TotalPusher Не работает данный метод. Испробовал его до создания вопроса. ДУмал, что может проблема в необычном пароле (знаки вопроса в пароле браузер расценивал как Get параметры), но даже после смены остается все также. Просто висит окно авторизации. Никаких действий далее предпринять не могу

Comment: Приложите HTTP логи. Их можно собрать разными способами, например через консоль разработчика, Сеть. Либо mitmproxy. Без этого искать проблему сложно. В этих логах должны быть заголовки авторизации.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте указать логин и пароль для доступа к сайту в url:

```
baseUrl = "https://%s:%s@bgoperator.ru/personal.jsp" % (login, password);
driver.get(baseUrl);
```

Comment: Я пробовал данный метод - не помогло. Возможно, конечно, что проблема в необычном пароле, которые имеет самый первый символ "?". Браузер двоеточие в слэш превращает и получается пароль выходит как get параметр (https:/username/?assword@bgoperator.ru/personal.jsp вот как-то так). Если смена пароля поможет - отмечу ваш ответ как лучший.